# Unable to create a new remote session. Appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am learning Appium, I am unable to create remote session tried changing devices still the same

error message:

```
 An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-78EHS656', ip: '192.168.137.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The instrumentation process cannot be initialized. Make sure the application under test does not crash and investigate the logcat output.
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
```

here's my code

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class AppiumTrialTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung A30");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "RR8M70339HL");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9"); //android version

        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sec.android.app.camera");//ung nasa appinfo apk
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,cap);


    }

}
```